# Android / Java: Sigmoid function to update double value

Tags: java, android, function, math, graph

I have a bunch of percentage values in the form of doubles that relate to system usage stats (things like cpu usage, memory etc) and I am trying to plug them into a sigmoid function to output a second double that relates to the severity of the first value.

I realise that sigmoid shaped functions would allow this to happen but I'm unsure about how to go about it.

For reference here is the kind of function I am referring to in graph form.

[image: Sigmoid graph]

With input along the x axis in the form of a percentage value 1-100 and output on the y axis in a 5 point value of severity so from 0-5, im attempting to map one percentage based value to an arbitrary value through a function.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: Well i don't know where to start in all honesty, how would you go about doing this? Math.exp maybe? just looking for some guidance after an hour of trying to find some answers online.

Comment: 10 seconds of Googling should have led you to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), which has the relevant function in the first three lines.

Comment: Already had the page open, been looking through it but I dont have a lot of experience with maths functions and graphs so it didnt mean an awful lot. How about the java side of things? How would i implements this once i figure out the correct mathematical function?

Comment: For instance im playing around with an online graph plotting sites to get the correct curve but even once I find out how would I map a percentage to another arbitrary value through the function is what i guess im saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a percentage `p` try

```
 Math.round(5.0/(1.0+Math.exp((50.0-p)/c)))
```

Here `c` controls the steepness of the transition from 0 to 5. A value of 10 looks about right to me.

Comment: Excellent answer, I just about managed to figure it out and used something that is basically this, but forgot to answer my own question :/ accepted and upvoted